# Getting MemoryError when appending to a list using a for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append

```
def show_magicians(magicians_list):
    """Print the name of each magician in a list."""
    for magician in magicians_list:
        print(magician.title())

def make_great(magicians_list):
    """Make each magician great again."""
    for magician in magicians_list:
        magician = magician + " " + "the Great"
        magicians_list.append(magician)

list_of_dudes = ['houdini','david blaine','jebus']

make_great(list_of_dudes)

show_magicians(list_of_dudes)

print(list_of_dudes)
```

Why is the second function not working? I'm trying to change each magician in the list of dudes to "[Magician] the Great" but I keep getting a memory error. Any advice?

Thank you,
-confused n00b

Comment: You are appending to the list while iterating over it so it is essentially an infinite loop.

Comment: You can replace your ```make_great``` method to something like ```magicians_list = [m + " the Great" for m in magicians_list]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be appending to the list, you should replace each element with its "great" version.

```
def make_great(magicians_list):
    """Make each magician great again."""
    for i, magician in enumerate(magicians_list):
        magician = magician + " " + "the Great"
        magicians_list[i] = magician
```

Your version is appending to the list that it's iterating over. As a result, it never ends, because it continues iterating over the new elements, and makes them even greater (`houdini the Great the Great`) and then iterates over those elements (`houdini the Great the Great the Great`) and so on until you run out of memory.